# Does GeneXus have the functionality to call external program's APIs?

Tags: api, genexus

I understand GeneXus has the 'External Object' feature, which I can only assume is used for setting up API calls, however, I can't seem to find any documentation online for doing this. I have an external software and I wish to run a GET API call (ie api.domain.com/example) and input the received data into a transaction in my GeneXus software. Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For calling HTTP APIs you should use the [HttpClient Data Type](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6932,HttpClient%20data%20type).

```
&httpclient.Host = "labs.genexus.com"
&httpclient.BaseUrl = "/mobilecrm/rest/"
&httpclient.Execute('GET','WorkWithDevicesCompany_Company_List_Grid?fmt=json')
&companies.FromJson(&httpclient.ToString() )
```

Look at this [sample](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20977,Consuming%20REST%20Data%20Providers%20in%20Genexus)

[External Objects](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6148,External%20Object%3A%20Native%20Object,) are used to integrate native objects, such as External Programs packaged as DLLS (.NET) or JARs (JAVA). This seems not to be your case.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very useful!